Distance to geometric median
The geometric median of a triangle is the point that minimizes the sum of distances to the triangle vertices. Is it true that for any triangle $ABC$ with geometric median $D$, and any other point $A'$, if we denote the geometric median of the triangle $A'BC$ by $D'$, then $|AD| \le |AD'|$?
At first glance, it seems that if we take $ABC$ to be an equilateral triangle (so $D$ is its centroid), and let $A'$ be such that $A'A$ is perpendicular to $BC$ (where $A$ is between $A'$ and $BC$), then we could have $|AD| > |AD'|$. However, calculations show that this is not true, the point $D'$ is the same as $D$, so $|AD| = |AD'|$. This leads me to think that the answer might be positive, but if so, how to prove it?

Both $D$ and $D'$ (if all the angles of the triangles are less than 120°) lie on the 120° circular arc of $BC$. But if $AB\ne AC$ then $D$ is not the point on that arc which is nearest to $A$. It is not difficult then to choose $A'$ such that $D'$ is the point of the arc nearest to $A$ (see figure below), to obtain $AD'<AD$.

